# upload index template to aws elasticsearch service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Thanks in advance!

I've exhausted google!

Basically I want to upload a index template json file to AWS Elasticsearch Service, how do I go about doing this? where does is go?

Here is the tutorial I am following which isn't very descriptive! 
https://www.fernandobattistella.com.br/log_processing/2016/03/13/Cloudtrail-S3-Lambda-Elasticsearch.html

Comment: Are you talking about the `PUT` request in the tutorial?

Comment: Yes thats right, the PUT & the following json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply run this and that should do the trick:

```
curl -XPUT http://search-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-xxxxxxx-1.es.amazonaws.com/_template/logstash -d '{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "_all" : {"enabled" : true, "omit_norms" : true},
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "message_field" : {
          "match" : "message",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "enabled" }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "string_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "enabled" },
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "doc_values" : true, "ignore_above" : 256}
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "float_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "float",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "float", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "double_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "double",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "double", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "byte_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "byte",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "byte", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "short_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "short",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "short", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "integer_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "integer",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "integer", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "long_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "long",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "long", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "date_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "date",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "date", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "geo_point_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "geo_point",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "geo_point", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      } ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date", "doc_values" : true },
        "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed", "doc_values" : true },
        "geoip"  : {
          "type" : "object",
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "ip": { "type": "ip", "doc_values" : true },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point", "doc_values" : true },
            "latitude" : { "type" : "float", "doc_values" : true },
            "longitude" : { "type" : "float", "doc_values" : true }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me! So what does that do exactly? and what about the json template provided in the tutorial?

Comment: I've not included the whole JSON in my answer (see the ellipsis?)

Comment: That will create an index template so that the next time a new document is created in an index whose name starts with `logstash-`, an index will be created with the template settings and mappings. See here for more info on index templates: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/indices-templates.html

Comment: Right with you! so I would need to insert the json where the ellipsis is?
Great thanks I will read that elastic reference guide!

Comment: I've modified my answer to include the full JSON. Also make sure to set the proper URL to hit your own instance.

Comment: ok so I've tried that and receive this error, any ideas on why that would be? 

Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'XPUT'.
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -XPUT http://search-XXXXXXXXX...
+      ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: On Powershell you don't have curl I guess. this might help then: https://superuser.com/questions/344927/powershell-equivalent-of-curl

Comment: ah I see! I will try it in another shell! So I tried the script in another one and it worked but then returned this error;

The requested URL co uld not be retrieved

error was encountered while trying to process the request:
 PUT /_template/logstash HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXX
User-Agent: curl/7.50.3
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 2954
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue

Comment: Maybe add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` as well to your curl call just after `-XPUT`

Comment: This solution worked as well! adding the extra content in type in returned an {"acknowledged":true} message! great going Val!
If anyone else comes across this make sure you have your access policy set up correctly.

Comment: Note that AWS does not support `_index_template` introduced in ES 7.8 so this is still the best answer. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_api_notes

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes across this the kibana interface has a console in dev tools on the left hand side where you can paste in the PUT JSON and run it, you should receive an acknowledged message in the right window

the URL should look like this - https://search-XXXX.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console?_g=()

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but cool if you made it work.

Comment: Well actually it was, that is how you upload an index to the aws elasticsearch service. instead of uploading the file you paste the jason into the kibana interface! Maybe on a normal elastic search instance you do it your way I can't say! Thanks for your help!

Comment: My answer used curl, yours used Kibana, the common point between both solutions is that you need to go through the HTTP REST API in order to interact with AWS ES :-)

Comment: That's correct! but using curl as you suggested returned errors

Comment: Can you share them so we can fix it and others who prefer to use curl don't fall in the same trap.

Comment: Cheers for your help Val! You definitely deserve the correct answer.